# vim - how to select and yank all comments?

Tags: vim, doxygen

I use doxygen documentation for c code.
Now I want to move these documentation to a saparate dox file.
Is there any quick and simple solution to yank these doxygen comments in vim?

```
/** 
 *....
 *....
 */ 

/*!
 *...
 *...
 *...
 */
```

I know I can use `y%` to yank all code in block when cursor is on first `/`. But our documentation is all over the file and it's hard to yank one by one.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty standard and general technique.

Press <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to clear register "a". Then enter command:

```
:g/regex1/ .,/regex2/ yank A
```

Where `regex1` is a regular expression to match the start of a block, and `regex2` matches the end of a block.

Now all relevant lines should get into register "a".

Answer (score 2):

I thik we need a non-greedy search to avoid coping everything from the first comment to the end of the second or last one. Something like this:

```
:let @a='' 
:g/\v^\/\*\_.{-}\*\//yank A
```

And as we are appending content to the register `A` it is recommended to clear it first, that's why `:let @a=''`.